# Expand the tag wiki for "article"

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I've noticed a number of recent questions on ELL that request advice using articles. To avoid having to list the basic rules of use, I would like to propose that the current tag wiki:

---

*Article* is the term used for a modifying word that introduce a noun phrase, and that implies that:

- The thing referred to is not specific (e.g. *she bought me a book*)
- The thing referred to has already been mentioned (e.g. *she bought me the book I wanted to buy last summer*)

In the first case, the article is the *indefinite article*; in the second case, the article is the *definite article*.

---

is extended with @DamkerngT. 's answer [here](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/17433/4559). This change would make the answer easier to find.

Comment: You're certainly welcome to propose a tag wiki edit! I do have to warn you that even really excellent tag wikis don't tend to have a huge effect though. People just don't often read them. (How to change that has been discussed on MSO before, I think.)